# C++ How to loop through a list of structs and access their properties

Tags: c++, list, loops, foreach, struct

I know I can loop through a list of strings like this:

```
list<string>::iterator Iterator;
 for(Iterator = AllData.begin(); 
   Iterator != AllData.end();
   Iterator++)
 {
  cout << "\t" + *Iterator + "\n";
 }
```

but how can I do something like this?

```
list<CollectedData>::iterator Iterator;
 for(Iterator = AllData.begin(); 
   Iterator != AllData.end();
   Iterator++)
 {
  cout << "\t" + *Iterator.property1 + "\n";
  cout << "\t" + *Iterator.property2 + "\n";
 }
```

or if someone can explain how to do this with a `for_each` loop, that would be very helpful as well, but it seemed more complicated from what I've read.

thank you so much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's as easy as `Iterator->property`.  Your first attempt is almost correct, it just needs some parentheses due to operator precedence: `(*Iterator).property`

In order to use for_each, you would have to lift the cout statments into a function or functor like so:

```
void printData(AllDataType &data)
{
    cout << "\t" + data.property1 + "\n";
    cout << "\t" + data.property2 + "\n";
}

for_each(AllData.begin(), AllData.end(), printData);
```

Answer (score 3):

`(*Iterator).property1` or `Iterator->property1`