# Iterating through a list of points in C++

Tags: list, iterator

I have a point3 struct that takes 3 floats x, y, z (3-D space coordinates).

I'm trying to write a function that translates the x, y, z values of each element in a list of points.

I'm new to C++ so I don't think I wrote the iterator correctly, can anyone help clarify how to iterate down a list and modify components of each element in the list?

I looked at this post [C++ How to loop through a list of structs and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355531/c-how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-structs-and-access-their-properties) and thought this answered my problem, but the solution didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
//Translates the face by dx, dy, dz coordinates
list<point3> translateFace(list<point3> lop, float dx, float dy, float dz)
{
    list<point3>::iterator iter;

    for (iter = lop.begin() ; iter != lop.end(); iter++){
        iter->x - dx;
        iter->y - dy;
        iter->z - dz;
    }
   return lop;
}
```

I also tried the solution suggested in the link above, still didn't work. Should *return lop* be inside or outside the for loop? Should I be returning something other than lop?

```
for (iter = lop.begin() ; iter != lop.end(); iter++){
    (*iter).x - dx;
    (*iter).y - dy;
    (*iter).z - dz;
    }
return lop;
```

Comment: "I'm new to C++" If you're new to C++, graphics programming is not where to start.

Comment: I didn't say I was new to graphics programming, simply that I was new to C++.

Comment: Even if you're good at graphics in other languages, it's still not a good place to start learning C++.

Comment: Not that it matters a year later, but instead of telling people "this isn't a good place to start" you should channel your energy towards, oh I don't know, actually helping them. If you take a peek at the accepted answer, you'll see that I had made a trivial mistake, being new to the language. My issue had nothing to do with the complexities of graphics programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you're not actually *storing* the results of your calculation:

```
for (iter = lop.begin() ; iter != lop.end(); iter++){
    iter->x - dx;
    iter->y - dy;
    iter->z - dz;
}
```

Try this:

```
for (iter = lop.begin() ; iter != lop.end(); iter++){
    iter->x -= dx;
    iter->y -= dy;
    iter->z -= dz;
}
```

I would hope most compilers would throw a warning about an unused calculation like this -- turn up the warning level on your compiler if you can.

Comment: You're correct, thank you very much! I don't know why my compiler didn't say anything, but I'll adjust the settings!

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
list<point3> translateFace(list<point3> lop, float dx, float dy, float dz)
{
    list<point3>::iterator iter;

    for (iter = lop.begin() ; iter != lop.end(); iter++){
        (*iter).x -= dx;
        (*iter).y -= dy;
        (*iter).z -= dz;
    }

    return lop;
}
```

Should be the correct option, assuming you know that When you do this, you're creating a local copy of the lop parameter, which is then returned and moved (C++0x) or copied (C++03) into whichever variable you are setting it to. For example (assuming point3 takes 3 floats to construct):

```
point3 point(0.0, 0.3, 0.5);
list<point3> face;

face = translateFace(list<point3>(point), -0.5, -3.32, -7.5);
```

should result in face containing a list holding only point, with coordinates -.5, -3.02 and -7.0.