# printing a struct with a map in it

Tags: c++, printing, dictionary, struct, hashtable

Ok I am having trouble printing the values in my list of structs. The normal way of printing a list (with the iterator) is not working. This is my code of me reading in a file into my list.

```
struct Edge{
    map<char, string> edge;
    int weight= -1;

    Edge(){};
    Edge(char v, string e, int w){
      edge.insert(pair<char,string>(v,e));
      weight = w;
    }
};

int main(){
     list<Edge> edges;

        //Read in file//
string line;
char start;
vector<string> tokens;

if(!file.is_open()){
    cout<<"Could not open file\n";
}else{
    while(getline(file,line)){
        tokens.clear();
        start = line.front();
        istringstream iss(line);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), 
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            back_inserter<vector<string>>(tokens));
        for(int i = 1; i<tokens.size(); i+=2){
            //cout << "Position: " <<i << " = " << tokens.at(i) <<endl;
            //insert into edges list.
                Edge e = Edge(start, tokens.at(i), stoi(tokens.at(i+1)));
                edges.push_back(e);
        }//end for
    }//end while
}//end if-else

 return 0;
}//end main
```

The vector tokens is read in properly. I checked it with the commented out cout.

The file is a graph file with the first element the start vertex and the rest of the line is formatted with the end vertex of the edge and the weight of that edge.

For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Would mean edge (1,2) has a weight of 3 and edge (1,4) has a weight of 5.

I don't know if I read in my list properly because I can't figure out how to print it out. How would I print out my list edges ?

Or is there a better way to set up my struct? Perhaps another struct for the edge and then a struct with the edge and weight?

Printing tried that won't work. The syntax doesn't even work. :(

The regular way to print a list. But doesn't like it since I have a struct list.

```
    list<Edge>::iterator it;
    for(it=edges.begin(); it!=edges.end(); it++){
    cout << *it <<endl;
}//end for
```

And this was what I found when I searched. This is what I found. 
[C++ How to loop through a list of structs and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355531/c-how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-structs-and-access-their-properties)
This is my attempt.

```
//inside main
    list<Edge>::iterator it;
for(int i = 0; i<edges.size(); i++){
    for_each(edges.begin(), edges.end(), printEdges);
}//end for

//outside main
    void printEdges(Edge &data){
    cout << "( " << data.edge << " )"
     << ": Weight = " << data.weight <<endl;
    }//end printEdges
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update to comment:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Edge const& edge)
{
    os << "Edge { weight:" << edge.weight << " {\n";
    for(edge_map::const_iterator it=edge.edge.begin(); it!=edge.edge.end(); ++it)
    {
        os << "{ '" << it->first << "', \"" << it->second << "\" } ";
    }
    return os << "\n}";
}
```

Should get you started.

1. it's `int main`, not `void main`
2. it's `weight = w;`, not `weight = w.`
3. You need to increment the loop variable. `i+2` has no effect. Did you mean `i+=2`?
4. If you did, the loop condition should be fixed to avoid out-of-bounds addressing:

   ```
       for(size_t i = 1; i+1<tokens.size(); i+=2){
   ```

   note the use of `size_t` to avoid mixed `signed`/`unsigned` comparison
5. the `Edge` constructor should initialize `weight`
6. If you need `//crutch comment`s, your code should be more legible :_)
7. Consider using a parser to read your input. You severely lack input validation, format flexibility and error handling.
8. Oh, don't use `using namespace std`

Here's an attempt at fixing some of the issues:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Edge{
    typedef std::map<char, std::string> edge_map;
    edge_map edge;
    int weight;

    Edge() : edge(), weight(0) {};
    Edge(char v, std::string e, int w) : edge(), weight(w)
    {
        edge.insert(std::pair<char,std::string>(v,e));
        weight = w;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Edge const& edge)
    {
        os << "Edge { weight:" << edge.weight << " {\n";
        for(edge_map::const_iterator it=edge.edge.begin(); it!=edge.edge.end(); ++it)
        {
            os << "{ '" << it->first << "', \"" << it->second << "\" } ";
        }
        return os << "\n}";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<Edge> edges;

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    std::ifstream file("input.txt");

    if(!file.is_open()){
        std::cout<<"Could not open file\n";
    }else{
        while(std::getline(file,line)){
            tokens.clear();
            char start = line.front();
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), 
                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                    std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>(tokens));
            for(size_t i = 1; i+1<tokens.size(); i+=2){
                Edge e = Edge(start, tokens.at(i), stoi(tokens.at(i+1)));
                edges.push_back(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't copy and paste. So those were in my code already. Except the initializing weight. I have changed them in the code on here now though.

Comment: Erm. That's just great. Feel free to pity-upvote. Maybe.

Comment: I was wonder how to print my list<Edge> edges. Since the regular way of printing a list isn't working (with an iterator from edges.begin() to edges.end()). Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: @user3342236 Erm. You didn't include any code related to printing? **Update** Does the update in the answer help?

Comment: Adding that and doing nothing else with it. Causes my program to endlessly run. I have to stop it manually. And if it did work, how would I call the printing of the list in main?

Comment: `Edge e; std::cout << e;` - if your program keeps running then either (a) your input stream is in a bad state and you fail to check it? (b) you still have a loop increment or condition that's broken (see 3. and 4.) (c) you have another issue :) Consider posting a new question with a http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Here's a demo, fixed a nasty typo (had a return that shouldn't be there) too: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fe50a71efb6495a